# Geoprocessing in web worker

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing

I would like to use a geoprocess using the esri js api from inside a web worker, can this be achieved?

I didn't manage to pass the geoprocessor to the web worker because it seems that  you can't pass an object with methods to a web worker and i'm not managing to load the module in the web worker because the basic esri api need window to be defined.